# Writing error messages in log file

Tags: ruby

I have a question about using logger library in writing the error messages to the log file.

I am trying to establish a db connection, and I want to print success or failure message in the log file. For example, if the user enters incorrect db port, then db connection cannot be established. In that case, I want to print `"NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection"` error in the log file.

Below is the piece of my code where I am doing it:

```
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:#{host}:#{port}/#{db}"
log = Logger.new('log.txt')
    log.level = Logger::WARN

con_props = java.util.Properties.new
    con_props.setProperty("user", usr)
    con_props.setProperty("password", pwd)

    conn=Java::Oracle.jdbc::OracleDriver.new.connect("#{url}", con_props)
    log.error "#{conn}"
```

This creates the log file, but it does not write a message in it. Can somebody help me with this?

Logfile looks like this:

```
# Logfile created on 2014-03-10 12:07:30 -0700 by logger.rb/v1.2.7
```

Comment: Try closing the log file at the end. `log.close`

Comment: Whats the result of `Java::Oracle.jdbc::OracleDriver.new.connect("#{url}", con_props)`? If the method returns nothing (nil), then the log can't contain a message. You could try `log.error "#{conn.inspect}"`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to print an *error* when the connection *fails*. If that's the case - you need to catch the `Exception`:

```
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:#{host}:#{port}/#{db}"
log = Logger.new('log.txt')
log.level = Logger::INFO

con_props = java.util.Properties.new
con_props.setProperty("user", usr)
con_props.setProperty("password", pwd)

begin
  conn=Java::Oracle.jdbc::OracleDriver.new.connect("#{url}", con_props)
  log.info "connection established!"
rescue => e
  log.error "Connection failed - #{e}"
  raise e
end
```

---

To create a `Logger` which appends to an existing file read the [documentation](http://apidock.com/ruby/Logger):

> Create a logger for the specified file.
>
> ```
> file = File.open('foo.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND)
> # To create new (and to remove old) logfile, add File::CREAT like;
> #   file = open('foo.log', File::WRONLY | File::APPEND | File::CREAT)
> logger = Logger.new(file)
> ```

Comment: Uri Agassi: Thank you, this works fine while creating a new log file. But how can I write the log message to the existing log file?

Comment: Uri Agassi: I am able to write to the existing log file now. But the error message is still printing on the screen. Instead I want to print a simple message, say, `Refer log.txt for further information`. How to do that?

Comment: @itsh - if you find that this answers your question - feel free to accept it. Added a description for how to append to a file.